# Can anyone tell me the grammar structures of the sentences below?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

1. He got her killed.
2. They have her caught.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners, @Tanha88 and thanks for your question. Just so you know, this question is very broad and has less detail than what is generally considered to be a good question by this community. It might not get answered well and it could be voted down. I suggest that you change this into two or more separate questions with narrower focuses and try to explain what you're confused about with regard to the meanings and structures of the two sentences.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of both of these sentences is

> Subject-verb-object-past participle

In this kind of construction, the past participle applies to the object of the main verb.

Looking at the first sentence, this is the entry for the appropriate meaning of **get**, from the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get):

> 3.2 **with object and past participle** Cause to be treated in a specified way.

The sentence as a whole means that he caused her to be killed, though it's not clear whether he did so by telling somebody to kill her or, for example, sending her on a dangerous mission.

---

In the second sentence, this meaning of **have**  from  the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have) would work:

> B1 [ T ] **to cause something to happen or someone to do something**:
>   **[ + past participle ]** We're having the house painted next month.
>   [ + infinitive without to ] If you wait, I'll have someone collect it for you.
>   [ + obj + -ing verb ] The film soon had us crying.
>   Gus will have it working in no time.
>   She had her parents down (= invited them to stay) for a week in the summer.
>   We had the boat out (= went out in the boat) for the first time this week.
>   We often have friends over/round (= invite them to come) on a Saturday night.

Note that the use of a past participle is sanctioned with this meaning. The sentence means that they have caused her to be in a situation where she is caught.

---

In the second sentence, **have** is present tense, which doesn't sit very well with **caught**. When talking about a person, **caught** means [to find and stop a person or animal that is trying to escape](http://to%20find%20and%20stop%20a%20person%20or%20animal%20that%20is%20trying%20to%20escape). It refers to the moment when somebody is stopped, rather than the state afterwards. You can use **caught in** statively, for example

> she is caught in a dilemma

Both **trapped** or **cornered** would work better, as they can refer to both event and state.

The sentence would be a lot more natural if it were modified in one of these ways, though the meaning for the first two would obviously be different:

> They had her caught
>   They have her caught in an impossible situation
>   They have her trapped